# Too many flips in pointfree Haskell?

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I'm learning Haskell using [Learn You A Haskell For Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions), and I came across this example:

```
ghci> sum (takeWhile (<10000) (filter odd (map (^2) [1..])))
166650
```

I thought to myself "well, that `10000` is dying to be parameterized". Using what knowledge I have so far I came up with a solution relying heavily on `(.)` and `flip`:

`flip (takeWhile . flip (<)) (filter odd (map (^ 2) [1..]))`

Well, ok we could use `>` instead<sup>*</sup>:

`flip (takeWhile . (>)) (filter odd (map (^ 2) [1..]))`

Basically, the pointy way of parameterizing out a variable is obvious. No matter where that expression occurs, we can very easily parameterize it out pain-free:

`odd_squares n = takeWhile (<n) (filter odd (map (^2) [1..]))`

but the point-free way I came up with to just parameterizing out a single variable seems a bit wild, especially the use of `flip` twice. At that point you're down in the weeds of things like "which order does `(<)` apply again?" and you're losing the entire benefit of pointfree abstraction.

Adding in the sum gives:

`sum $ flip (takeWhile . flip (<)) (filter odd (map (^ 2) [1..]))`

Many delimiters, a `$`, `(.)` and `flip`.

So, I am guessing that there must be a much easier way of going about parameterizing a variable in a function expression like this. Any hints pointing me in the right direction? I've looked at other posts on stackoverflow which have taken me to https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree, but it doesn't help me much since they pick nice clean examples that by pure chance don't require `flip`.

Some of the other posts that come up on stackoverflow are more like "hey, make this pointfree for me" requests, and the answers often just go ahead and use a bunch of flips, ending up with unreadable functions. My question is more along the lines of "pointfree is good, you can abstract away data wrangling details, but once you use flip a bunch you're back in the data wrangling weeds, so what other tools are available to help you to pointfree well?"

<sup>*Although that's beside the point: if `(<)` didn't have a flipped version with another name, we'd have had to flip it, so in general I think the line above is more representative of the process I'm using here and how you'll end up with a bunch of `flip`'s.</sup>

Comment: Although likely not what you are looking for, the sum of squares can easily be turned into an expression that does not sums a *list*, but thus calculates the sum of the list directly.

Comment: Of *course* there's a much easier way of going about parameterizing a variable in a function expression: name it. `\n -> sum (takeWhile (<n)) (filter odd (map (^2) [1..]))` can be produced in a completely mechanical way, and is almost identically as readable as the original, non-parameterized version. It's great! Use it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`flip` is a fairly low-level tool for writing pointfree code; it’s generally not very readable, especially when the flipped expression is long or there are multiple flips.

Good rules of thumb:

- Use a flipped version of an operator instead of `flip` if available:

  - `(>)` ↔︎ `(<)`
  - `(>>=)` ↔︎ `(=<<)`
- Use a section of a function instead of `flip` if it’s still readable:

  - `flip map xs` = `` (`map` xs) ``
- Use `Applicative` combinators to pass arguments as a reader “environment”:

  - `(f <$> g) x = f (g x)`
  - `(f <*> g) x = f x (g x)`
  - `liftA2 f x y = f <$> x <*> y`
- For manipulating multiple arguments, wrap them in a tuple and use `curry` on the outside to present a normal curried type:

  - ```
    multiplyAdd :: Num a => a -> a -> a -> a
    multiplyAdd = fmap curry $ curry
      $ (*) <$> fst <*> ((+) <$> fst . snd <*> snd . snd)
    ```
- Use `Arrow` and tuple combinators for manipulating tupled values:

  - `(f *** g) (x, y) = (f x, g y)`
  - `(f &&& g) x = (f x, g x)`
  - `swap ~(x, y) = (y, x)`
  - `both f ~(x, y)` = `(f x, f y)`
- Factor definitions into many small parts

```
sumOddSquaresLessThan = sum <$> oddSquaresLessThan
  where

    -- Alternatives:
    --
    -- * ‘(>)’ instead of ‘flip (<)’
    --
    -- * ‘flip takeWhile oddSquares <$> …’
    --   instead of ‘… <*> pure oddSquares’
    oddSquaresLessThan = takeWhile <$> flip (<) <*> pure oddSquares
    oddSquares = filter odd squares
    squares = map (^ 2) [1 ..]
```

Here `(f <$> g) x` = `(f . g) x` = `f (g x)`, mapping “under” a parameter (the B combinator); `(f <*> g) x = f x (g x)` is applying with a parameter (the S combinator); and `pure x y` = `const x y` = `x`, ignoring the parameter (the K combinator). This is essentially the standard “abstraction algorithm” for converting a lambda-calculus expression to combinator calculus (SKI, BCKW): replace application with S, wrap constants in K, use a parameter with I (identity), and map under a parameter with B.

Answer (score 4):

Let `oddsquares = filter odd (map (^2) [1..]`; that won't change, and it just detracts from the readability of the rest.

```
sum (takeWhile (<10000) (filter odd (map (^2) [1..])))
  == sum (takeWhile (<10000) oddsquares)
```

Start by moving `(< 10000)` closer to the end of the expression.

```
  == sum (flip takeWhile oddsquares (<10000))  -- f x y == flip f y x
```

Then you can introduce a couple of composition operators and a `flip` (to get the `(<)` section correct):

```
  == sum . flip takeWhile oddsquares . flip (<) $ 10000  -- f (g x) == f . g $ x
```

---

You can of course replace `flip (<)` with `(>)` (since `\x -> x < 10000` is equivalent to `\x -> 10000 > x`)

```
  == sum . flip takeWhile oddsquares . (>) $ 10000
```

---

Jon Purdy raises a good point about using sections to eliminate `flip`. I don't mind judicious usage of `flip` myself, but in the interest of completeness,

```
sum . (`takeWhile` oddsquares) . (>) $ 10000
```